# Fill in an EditText with data from a Database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-edittext

I would like to retrieve data from a SQLite database, and put that value into an EditText (in the layout of the Activity) and display it...

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please give us some code that we can work on.

Comment: @BinoyBabu  
I would just like to retrieve the data previously entered by the user (I know how to do it) and put it into the EditText in the xml file : `<EditText android:id="@+id/idETTitleU" android:inputType="text" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/labelTitleU" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />` Do you know which attribute I should specify into the EditText tag?

Comment: please? I really need help for that :(

Comment: @d1212, if you know how to do part of it (retrieve the data), post that code already (in the question, not in comments) and then we can help fill in what you are missing...

Answer (score 2):

[here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/use-of-sqlite/) is a tutorial that I went through when I was facing problem in writing and reading data to SQLite data base. [And here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html) is the second tutorial for doing so but I recommend you to follow the first one since its more descriptive.